# How to use node modules correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I am a CS student with a strong Java background, and javascript is resulting to be a challenging but fun experience so far, that is until I ran into the situation where I tried to use my own modules to return values that require the program to wait for the completion of some procedure before returning.

---

So far no-one from any forum that I have posted this question on has been able to give an actual code fix to the problem, they have referred me to read further material that is not related to the problem at hand. 
 Would anyone please read the code and provide a working correct standard solution to the problem I am facing?
Here is the code, a simple nodes server application, app.js and a weather module, weatherApp.js that uses an user provided zip code and returns a weather forecast in the area.

here is the code:
**weatherApp.js**

```
// The required modules.
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");


    //result object
    var resultSet = {
        googleRequestUrl:"",
        forecastIOrequest:"",
        latitude :"",
        longitude:"",
        localInfo:"",
        weather:"",
        humidity:"",
        pressure:"",
        time:""
    };

    //print out error messages
    function printError(error){
        console.error(error.message);
    }

    //Forecast API required information:
    //key for the forecast IO app
    var forecast_IO_Key = "bb9aac7c57877f8f5fab339e3b55669a";
    var forecast_IO_Web_Adress = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/";


    //Create Forecast request string function
    function createForecastRequest(latitude, longitude){
        var request = forecast_IO_Web_Adress + forecast_IO_Key + "/"
                          + latitude +"," + longitude;
        return request;
    }

    //Google GEO API required information:
    //Create Google Geo Request
    var google_GEO_Web_Adress =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

    function createGoogleGeoMapRequest(zipCode){
        var request = google_GEO_Web_Adress+zipCode + "&sensor=false";
        return request;
    }


    // 1- Need to request google for geo locations using a given zip
    function connectToGoogleGEO(zipCode, afterCallback){
        var googleRequest = https.get(createGoogleGeoMapRequest(zipCode), function(response){
            //saving the Google request URL
            resultSet.googleRequestUrl = createGoogleGeoMapRequest(zipCode);
            var body = "";
            var status = response.statusCode;
            //a- Read the data.
            response.on("data", function(chunk){
                body+=chunk;
            });
            //b- Parse the data.
            response.on("end", function(){  
                if(status === 200){
                   try{
                       var googleReport = JSON.parse(body);
                       resultSet.latitude = googleReport.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                       resultSet.longitude = googleReport.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

             resultSet.localInfo = googleReport.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + ", " +
                                   googleReport.results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ", " +
                                   googleReport.results[0].address_components[2].long_name + ", " +
                                   googleReport.results[0].address_components[3].long_name + ". ";
                                   // callback to forecast IO.

                       afterCallback(resultSet.latitude, resultSet.longitude);  
                   }catch(error){
                       printError(error.message);
                   }finally{
                    // nothing here
                   } 
                }else{
                    printError({message: "Error with GEO API"+http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode]})
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function connectToForecastIO(latitude,longitude){
        var forecastRequest = https.get(createForecastRequest(latitude,longitude),function(response){
           resultSet.forecastIOrequest = createForecastRequest(latitude,longitude);
            var body = "";
            var status = response.statusCode;
            //read the data
             response.on("data", function(chunk){
                body+=chunk;
            });
            //parse the data
            response.on("end", function(){
                try{
                    var weatherReport = JSON.parse(body);
                    resultSet.weather = weatherReport.currently.summary;
                    resultSet.humidity = weatherReport.currently.humidity;
                    resultSet.temperature = weatherReport.currently.temperature;
                    resultSet.pressure = weatherReport.currently.pressure;
                    resultSet.time = weatherReport.currently.time; 
                }catch(error){
                    printError(error.message);
                }finally{
                  console.log(resultSet);

                }
            });
        });    
    }


    function get(zipCode){
        var results = connectToGoogleGEO(zipCode, connectToForecastIO);
        return results;
    }

    //define the name of the outer module.
    module.exports.get = get;
```

And here is the server code: 
**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var weatherApp = require("./weatherApp.js");
var path = require("path");
var http = require("http");
var app = express();

//creating routes
//The home
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/weather");
});
app.get("/weather", function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});
//------------------------------------------------------
//The resources, css, web js files, images etc.
app.get("/StyleSheets/style.css", function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/StyleSheets/style.css"));
});
app.get("/webScripts/app.js", function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/webScripts/app.js"));
});
app.get("/webImages/swirl_pattern.png", function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/webImages/swirl_pattern.png"));
});
//-------------------------------------------------------
//other requests

app.get("/zipcode.do", function(req, res){
    var zipcode = req.query["zipcode"];
    var response = "No report Available";

    function getReport(zipCode, callback){
        response = weatherApp.get(req.query["zipcode"]);
    }
    getReport(zipcode, ()=>{
       res.send("<p>" + response+ "</p>"); 
    }); 
});

//any other entry thats not listed as a valid to request
app.get("/:title", function(req,res){
    var title = req.param.title;
    if(title === undefined){
       var status = res.status(503);
        res.send("This page does not exists" + '"' + http.STATUS_CODES[503] + '"');
    }else{
        res.send(title);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server running at port: 3000")
});
```

---

The main issue I am having right now is:

1. The program is not returning anything from the module even when final console.log in the weather module prints the right resultSet object.
2. The server is not waiting for the module to return, and continues to print no data.

Can someone provide a working fix to any of these problems I would be really grateful, This has really hindered my progress and broken down my morale a little :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using asynchronous functions as if they were synchronous.

It might not be the only issue here, but this function is particularly problematic:

```
function get(zipCode){
    var results = connectToGoogleGEO(zipCode, connectToForecastIO);
    return results;
}
```

`connectToGoogleGEO()` calls [the asynchronous `https.get()` function](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) and does not return the data that is retrieved from Google. You need to rewrite your code so that it does not expect the data to be returned by the function. Instead, you need to pass a callback that will handle the data.

Take care to know when you are calling asynchronous functions and how their callbacks work. It is fundamental when working with Node.js